# Ignore undefined props

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am passing an object like this into a component:

```
obj = {
   prop1: 1,
   prop2: 2,
   prop3: 3
}
<my-component :data="obj"></my-component>
```

the component only has these two defined, by design, because I want to ignore what is not defined:

```
    props: {
        prop1: Number,
        prop2: Number
    }
```

what's happening is when the component is rendered, the root node looks like this with the undefined prop placed like an attribute?!:

```
<div prop3="3">
   ...
</div>
```

I don't want undefined props to be de-structured by the component and definitely don't want them to rendered in the root element. I want them to be ignored. Is there a flag or some setting to say ignore all undefined props?

Please don't say why I would ever need this. I do because these objects are built somewhere else and don't want to create new subset objects just for this purpose.

Comment: It is exactly the other way around: you set attributes on an element and Vue removes those attributes it recognizes (directives, listeners, properties, etc.). Hence, you cannot tell vue to 'ignore' attributes - because it already does.

Comment: OK but I am looking for a solution to prevent it from rendering the undefined props in the root element like so: ```<div prop3="3">...</div>```. To me it doesn't make sense why its doing it not have I seen any documentation on this behavior.

Comment: Do not set them! Or set only the entire object as prop and restructure it in your child components (e.g. in a computed property)

Comment: 1. Already said in my post that not sending them is not an option. 2. Setting the entire object as a prop will not do validation on each element and I need that. What's the point of defining props if it consumes the undefined ones anyway?

Comment: Having them reactive and available on the Vue instance (and validateable as you mentioned). Regular attributes are only available on the HTML element. - the best way to do what you want is to filter the object for the properties you want before binding the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
    props: {
        prop1: Number,
        prop2: Number
    },
    inheritAttrs: false
```

This will tell Vue to not add additional props to the element as attribute but those props will instead be stored in `$attrs`, so you could access your prop using `this.$attrs.prop3`

See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance